# Nodejs - How to write a api that calls every minute

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I wanted to write a Api that calls every minute in my application.

I have tried the scheduler in firebase but in wanted to write it in my application.

please find the solution for this problem. that would be helpful.

thank you

Comment: Did you try `setInterval`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node-cron library allows you to schedule tasks to run at specific intervals using cron syntax.

```
npm install node-cron
```

Example:

```
const cron = require('node-cron');

// Schedule a cron job to run a function every minute
cron.schedule('* * * * *', () => {
  console.log('Cron job executed!');
});
```

`* * * * *` - This will generate a function every minute. You can customize it as per your requirements

For the generate cron job string you can use this [link](https://crontab.guru/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cron job and schedule it for every minute.

```
const { CronJob } = require('cron');

const Job = new CronJob({
  cronTime: '*/1 * * * *',

  callFn();
});

callFn() {
// Code
}

Job.start();
```

Comment: This looks like invalid js?...